# Converting HTML Entity to Raw HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have this string:

```
'&lt;div class="md"&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.google.com/"&gt;Foo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;/div&gt;'
```

which I'm trying to display as:

```
Foo
```

So I'm trying to convert the original string to raw HTML.

I've tried:

```
raw '&lt;div class="md"&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.google.com/"&gt;Foo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;/div&gt;'
```

which converts the entity to normal HTML but displays it as a string:

```
<div class="md"><p><a href="http://www.google.com/">Foo</a></p> </div>
```

I've also tried html_safe and html_safe.html_safe but those are giving me the same results.

So how do I convert a string containing HTML entities to raw HTML to be rendered in Rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CGI.unescapeHTML('&lt;div class="md"&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.google.com/"&gt;Foo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;/div&gt;').html_safe
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip !